# "I to have been" instead of "I would have been"?

Tags: conditional-constructions, infinitives

In *Breaking Bad Extras* an actor talks about a scene in which he would wish to be part of:

> ..for some reason that episode is just lodged in my mind and **I to have been a fly on the wall** or a roach in the corner ... I feel *I would have been pretty fascinating*.

[this moment on YouTube](https://youtu.be/Yiu-fevbJy8?t=218)

Could someone explain this usage?
Is it equal to "I would have been a fly"?
What kind of a stylistic flair does it add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dialogue goes
"For some reason that episode is just lodged in my mind, and I... I... to have been a fly on the wall or a roach in the corner... I feel like would have been pretty fascinating."

The two words "I" in succession are hesitations before the speaker reformulated his thought. The sense is "I feel ...[that] to have been a fly on the wall would have been pretty fascinating". That means that he thinks he would like to have been a hidden observer, to see and hear everything, not that he would have participated.
Try googling "fly on the wall".

Comment: Thank you. I initially thought about it, but decided it's better to ask. The pause was subtle.